# How to represent a loop with a "continue" statement from C in a PlantUML activity diagram

Tags: c, uml, activity-diagram, plantuml

I need to convert C code below to an activity diagram using PlantUML.

What is a good solution to implement the "continue" statement from the code below ?

```c
    void function_1(){
    int a = 0;
    int b =0;
      for (int i; i < 8; i++)
      {
        if (i < 2)
        {
           continue;
        }
        if (i > 4)
        {
            a = 1;
        }           
        else
        {
           b = 2;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   Your code will never do anything except be in an infinite loop because you set `i=5` every time it loops around.

Comment: The code just for example with continue statement. Anyway, I corrected the code. Thank you

Comment: Plantuml is a little restricted when it comes to representable language constructs. A workaround might be necessary to get as close as possible to the desired output. Can you clarify what the desired output is? This is one of the (in my opinion) rare occasions where a picture would be helpful. Maybe even of a handdrawn diagram. Or you could try to find online an example which looks similar to what you want.

Comment: The part with `if (i < 2) {continue;}` actually means that you need to do nothing in that case. Therefore, just pretend that it does not exist. This should be fine, if I understand the desired outcome correctly.

Comment: @virolino: if (i < 2) {continue;} will not do anything, but should present in diagram.

Comment: I do not know plantuml, but the better solution is to delete it from the C code, in the first place - why have it at all, if it is useless? Just redesign the C code.

Comment: `i` is used uninitialised. Not good.

Comment: Do you want to draw sequence diagramme or an activity diagramme ? Your post title says one thing and the description another.

Comment: @virolino Why do you think, it is useless? If you remove that part, the code will enter the `else` branch which it will not do with the `continue`.

Comment: @Gerhardh: you misunderstood my intention (maybe the words I used were confusing). The desired meaning was actually "redesign the C code", rather than "delete blindly whatever you can". For details, please also see my answer below.

Comment: @virolino Now I see. You are right.

Comment: Sequence diagram and activity diagram are different types of UML diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know C but it seems to me that one way of representing your logic in PlantUML would be as follows:

```
start
while (i < 8 ?)
  if (i > 4 ?) then (yes)
      :a = 1;
  else (no)
      if (i >= 2 ?) then (yes)
      :b = 2;
      else (no)
      endif
  endif
 endwhile (no)
:Carry out the next task;
end
```

The "Carry out the next task" task is a placeholder. It should be replaced with whatever your application is supposed to do next.

Which yields [the following diagramme](https://liveuml.com/view/5dbc2203663178088afee658):

[image]

Comment: Looks to me that you are missing the for loop. The continue statement means (Kerningham and Ritchie, The C programming Language 1978, pg 203 and 62): causes control to pass to the loop-continuation portion of the smallest enclosing while, do or for statement; that is to end the loop. On another place it states: it causes the next iteration of the enclosing loop (for,while,do) to begin.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @albert. I added the `while` statement in the plantUML diagramme.

Comment: As a side note with an `elseif` the diagram does even look better (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of converting the code to another language or not, I would optimize it the following way, in the first place:

```
void function_1(){
int a = 0;
int b =0;
  for (int i=0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (i > 4)
    {
        a = 1;
    }           
    else if ( i >= 2 )
    {
       b = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        /* - nothing to do */
        /* - this statement is here as proof that we do not want to handle
        /*   other cases, as opposed to just forgetting about them */
        /* - it can be used in the future for extension, as needed */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that someone already provided an answer, suggesting to rearrange the if blocks so that the continue statement is the last one. However, this approach may not always be feasible, especially if there are other statements after the if statement, such as assignments. In such cases, I suggest considering the continue as another loop inside the big loop. While this may create a bit messier code, it will achieve the same behavior as continue. Therefore, my proposed solution is:

```
@startuml
start
:Set a = 0;
:Set b = 0;
:Initialize i;
repeat
    repeat
        :statments before continue;
    
    repeat while (i < 2) 
    -> No;
    if (i > 4) then (yes)
    :Set a = 1;
    else (no)
    :Set b = 2;
    endif
    :Increment i;
repeat while (i < 8);
stop
@enduml
```